# How to compare to datatable with different columns

Tags: c#, system.data.datatable

I have the `EMP` datatable it contains 500 records  like this:

```
UserAceNumber     UserID    

emp001           
emp002         
emp003         
emp004
```

(userid will be empty for all the 500 records)

Another `Empdetails` datatable contains some records which I will keep UserID in this table like this:

```
UserAceNumber     UserID    

emp002           user002         
emp004           user004
```

I need the result in the `EMP` table like this:

```
UserAceNumber UserID     
emp001       
emp002        user002   
emp003        
emp004        user004
```

In this both table common value is `UserAceNumber`

I cant use any SQL queries because these datatables are coming from webservices and also the LINQ because I am using 2005

How to do this? I have done merge but but I need the columns as if in `EMP` datatable.

Comment: "here i cant use any sql queries because these datatables are coming from database" - doesn't make sense, presumably you meant to write ARE NOT coming from a database?

Comment: I think your best option is to Change the Database schema or create a view that merges both and then use C# to retrieve the values from that view or updated schema... There are many ways you can achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Datatable.Select` query to achieve this the output will be a datarow.

```
var dataRow=dataTable.Select(string.Format("{0}='{1}'", primaryKeyColumnName, valueOfPrimaryKey));
```

For more infor about the API look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx)

Basically what you do is loop over one of the datatables identify the primary key column in this datatable use that to find a corresponding row in the second datatable

Comment: nice approach, will use it myself :)

Comment: primaryKeyColumnName,valueOfPrimaryKey what should i give?

Comment: In this how to compare with another datatable

Comment: whatever the distinct key is in each of the datatabe that will let you select the necessary row from the datatable